# How to identify generic relationship after model is passed to React

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I've built a Django app with a React frontend. Now, I want to use generic relationships and not sure of a reliable way for my React app to identify which model the relationship is.

I've considered :

1. adding a new field to my model to keep track of the model type but this seems counter to the idea of generic relationships
2. Looking at the fields of the object once it reaches my react app to determine what the model is. But this seems difficult to maintain as things grow.

I use 100% Typescript in my React, so perhaps there is some way to leverage Typescript to help.

What is a good way to identify different models in generic relationships once they reach the React app?

Comment: I'm not familiar with what Django's generic relations are exactly, but perhaps [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) could be what you're looking for?

Comment: I am familiar with discriminated unions. However, I believe, in this case, they would only be good for identifying if the model were one of the models in the union, not which model it is. Maybe I'm wrong though.

Comment: Does the model include the type of the model as a string or some other type of identifier?